# Read and display an Open Office spreadsheet

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, openoffice.org, openoffice-calc

I need to find a solution to read and display an Open Office spreadsheet, inside my AIR application.

I found some information about excel but nothing about Open office.

My wish is to open openoffice calc document inside my air application, I have a dream...

Thanks for helping

Comment: Unless you write your own parser to parse the file format; and your own way to display it; this probably isn't going to be possible.

Comment: At least you can convert your spreadsheet to swf and load it. See [here](http://www.verydoc.com/blog/how-to-convert-openoffice-calc-to-swf-easily.html) or try using [print2flash](http://print2flash.com/)

Answer (score 0):

I didnt try my self but you can use move as Flextras suggest to do this you can use [Read Text](http://extensions.services.openoffice.org/en/project/Read_Text) an extension to open office, with Flex [Iframe](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=AboutHTMLEnvironment_5.html) or as you like

Alternatively you may use Ulteo an Open office web viewer see [this](http://downloadsquad.switched.com/2007/12/12/run-openoffice-org-in-a-web-browser-no-installation-necessary/) with Flex [Iframe](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=AboutHTMLEnvironment_5.html) ,

[Sample IFrame Application](http://www.deitte.com/IFrameDemo3/IFrameDemo.html)

Hopes that helps

Comment: Thanks for helping, but can you explain to me why Read Text can help me. Indeed Read Text seems to speech text to blind people. Thanks

Comment: I think it have implemented logic to read(get contents) from calc  which may help you to implement your logic to read data. if you go for parser you may find other options too

Answer (score 0):

I recently wrote an as3 exporter for xlsx depending on your feature requirements (data only should be pretty simple cause like the office x formats the open office formats are xml based) I would start here http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenDocument and look up the full spec.  If the docs are compressed use the no chump as3 zip library.